# Vertical Line in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, editor, code-editor

I don't know why but sometime in Android Studio Editor, it shows **vertical line** as shown in screenshot below.

Don't know about other editor but it happens in Android Studio.

> **So why it is showing and how to hide it?**

[image: Android Studio shows Vertical Line in Editor]

Answer (score 147, accepted):

That line historically represents the margin of A4 paper, which is useful only if you need to print the code.
Old school says that you should keep your code inside that margin, to guarantee much portability.

But.. nowadays in the real life, it makes no sense to me! Because we always use advanced editors, bigger displays, and I never needed to print any single line of code.

So, if you want to do it:

#### Newer versions

> Editor -> General -> Appearance -> Show hard wrap guide

#### Older versions

> Editor -> General -> Appearance -> Show right margin

or

> Editor -> Appearance -> Show right margin

#### For Mac

> To remove line go to:-  Preference-> Editor -> General -> Appearance -> Show hard wrap and visual guides. Uncheck it to remove.

Comment: for me it's indicated as "Show hard wrap guide"

Comment: Updated the answer with @IvoBeckers suggestion

Comment: One and a half year late to the party but since this is a somewhat popular question I'd like to ad something. Whenever you go past this line there is a way to clean up your code and make it more readable. It's good practice to not cross this line, at leas not by many characters since it really is not needed if you properly refactor and layout your lines of code. You will do your future self and others reading your code a huge favor.

Comment: I´m not familiar with the historical origin you mention. The current objective of that line is to keep lines to a conventional readable length.

Comment: If you just want to push that line further away, then in Mac, go to Settings -> Editor -> Code Style -> Change "Hard wrap at" to your desired value.

Answer (score 17):

It is as follows in the newer version of Android Studio:

#### Editor -> General -> Appearance -> Show hard wrap guide

Answer (score 7):

**im Mac**

Open Android Studio and Click

```
cmd + ,
```

and follow this step:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Android Studio has changed layout again, so you can find this option at:

**File -> Settings -> Editor -> General -> Appearance -> Show hard wrap and visual guides**

As it is mentioned earlier, if your code is of that length, it is pretty obvious that it is not that readable, i.e. clean. Being old school, I keep it at 80 characters and spill occasionally.