# How to increase code view's width from Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

How to increase code view's width from Android Studio ?

[image]

Thank you very much

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vertical Line in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41585002/vertical-line-in-android-studio)

Answer (score -1):

Of course you can. It's a wrap guide, which can be defined in the code style

[image]